# Get DOM elements in an object in one short statement

Tags: jquery

I have the following form:

```
<div class="container">
   <div clas="row">
        <form>
            <div id="name">
                <input class="form-control" name="user_name" value="John Doe" id="user_name">
            </div>
            <div class="check">
                <label for="priority">Priority</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="priority" id="priority" value="1"/>
            </div>
            <div class="check">
                <label for="can-wait">Can Wait</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="can-wait" id="can-wait" value="1"/>
            </div>
            <div class="check">
                <label for="when-possible">When Possible</label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="when-possible" id="when-possible" value="1"/>
            </div>
            <ol id="check-list" >
                <li><input type="text" name="taskdesc" value="" class="form-control"/></li>
                <li><input type="text" name="tododesc" value="" class="form-control"/></li>
                <li><input type="text" name="donedesc" value="" class="form-control"/></li>
            </ol>

        </form>
   </div>

</div>
```

I need a jQuery object containing the first div in the container, all the checkbox that are in the second div, and the inputs which are in the ordered list.
   I have tried to do this iterating trough the elements and retrieve the ones I need, but the code is to messy and not really easy readable.

I am looking for a shortcut to do this in one go.
   It is possible?

Comment: `$('.container, .container input[type="checkbox"], .container ol input')`

Answer (score 0):

It is almost what I was looking for, but I asked also to get the fist div, so I have changed your short cut a little and I came to this:

```
var controls = $( "div#name, div.check, ol#check-list li > input[name$='desc']" )
```

Comment: The first DIV in your markup would be `.container`, not `#name`, so blame yourself

Comment: @adeneo you are completely right , and I have updated my question to reflect what I really meant. I didn't want to get the container. But by the way thanks to point to this. Next time I will read my question carefully before I am going to post  it .

Comment: @adeneo I felt a little bad the last few days. I realize that at the time you have answered  my question ''Due to lack, from my side, to mention the first div in the container" your answer was right. So it will be right for me  to up vote it. I apologize again for this :)

Comment: I just posted a comment, don't worry about it. You can accept your own answer and get the points.

Comment: I was not doing this for the points, it was the first time I posted a question. So Looking at you guys I was learning how to manage it.

Answer (score 0):

if you need only container div and inputs inside:

```
var jq = $('.container').clone().html($('.container :checkbox, .container #check-list input'));
```